# Android - control an led with button in android

Tags: java, android, led

is there a way of building a simple circuit with an led bulb, and somehow control it with an android device. if so, how. is it possible to do this without Arduino, I don't know much about Arduino, but I'm looking for a pure solution.

Comment: You will need a bridge that accepts commands from android and then operates a module that can trigger LED. a 8051 should do fine. you will need a way to connect 8051 with Android and then you can write few line of assembly for 8051 that can accept command from Android on one port and trigger a circuit on other that drives LED. obviously different LEDs will have different voltage operation range so you will require a driver circuit.

Comment: @Ankit what language does an 8051 use

Comment: you can use Assembly or C. few steps to get you started:: android to 8051 -> http://www.gadgetronicx.com/interfacing-bluetooth-module-with-8051-hc05/. driving LED with 8051 -> http://www.mytutorialcafe.com/Microcontroller%20Application%20C%20Led.htm. Note:: 8051 is for example. its easy to use. Simple to adapt for beginners, but is not the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micro controller and communication medium both are important for controlling any hardware device.
You can use any micro controller or you can design your own by using 8051 IC

Comment: what language does a 8051 use

Comment: Embedded C, you have to use keil, protious softwares to code 8051, but will recommend to use arduino instead. Beacause you have to design full circuit for 8051 and use pocket programmer to code in it